# Call a method in application scope (.Net)

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, scope, master-pages

I have a UserControl(uc) in my master page, and a method(MyMethod) inside uc that make some calculations.

```
protected void Page_Load()
{
 If(!IsPostBack)
  MyMethod();
}

private void MyMethod()
{    
  SomeCalculations..
}
```

Because my uc is in master page, i can see the uc in all my aspx pages. My aim is that as soon as a user login the application, run MyMethod() just once (in a thread) and do calculations in an infinite loop until the user logout or application (or browser) closed. Although the calculations are outside of the PostBack, MyMethod will be called more than one time.

Assume that I m in Page-1 and it s loaded first time, MyMethod() will bi called. After another page (Page-2) is loaded, MyMethod will be called again and I want to prevent it. Is there a way to do something like this:

```
if(LifeCycle of application resumes)
{
  MyMethod()
}
```

Comment: Can you use session variable to store state ?

Comment: I m not sure old session will remain or another new session will be created, when a different page is loaded. Because of this my idea was to do it in application scope not session scope..

Answer (score 1):

You can store a flag in [application state](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94xkskdf.aspx) and use it in a condition.  Something like this, perhaps:

```
// in Application_Start in Global.asax
Application["IsRunning"] = false;
```

then:

```
private void MyMethod()
{
    if (!((bool)Application["IsRunning"]))
    {
        Application["IsRunning"] = true;

        // your code
    }
}
```

Note that the state of a web application isn't always stable or intuitive.  It's really meant to be a request/response system and is at the mercy of the web server for managing resources.  This *may* not be as reliable as you expect.

You might want to consider having a separate application, such as a Windows Service, for performing ongoing background tasks.